# API Platform 2.5.7 - Setting the returned @type when using a DTO

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Using API Platform 2.5.7 and Symfony 4.4.

In order to handle some transformations when responding to a GET request for an entity, I implemented a DTO and an OutputDataTransformer.

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/

The original API would return a JSON object such as:

```
                {
            "@id": "/api/records/1",
            "@type": "Record",
            "id": 1,
            "content": "auth1.dns.mydomain.com hostmaster.mydomain.com 2004021303 3600 900 604800 3600",
            "name": "mydomain.com",
            "ttl": 3600,
            "type": "SOA",
            "zone": {
                "@id": "/api/zones/1",
                "@type": "Zone",
                "id": 1,
                "name": "mydomain.com",
                "type": "NATIVE",
                "recordCount": 7
            },
            "priority": 0
        },
```

The entity now has an output config in the ApiResource annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="records")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\RecordRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *     output=RecordOutput::CLASS,
 *     normalizationContext={"groups": {"records"}}
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, properties={"id", "name", "content", "type", "disabled", "zone.name", "priority", "ttl"}, arguments={"orderParameterName": "order"})
 * @Assert\GroupSequenceProvider
 */
class Record implements GroupSequenceProviderInterface
{
```

But after implementing the transformer such as:

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTransformer;

use ApiPlatform\Core\DataTransformer\DataTransformerInterface;
use App\Dto\RecordOutput;
use App\Entity\Record;

class RecordOutputDataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Record $record
     */
    public function transform($record, string $to, array $context = [])
    {
        $output = new RecordOutput();

        // transform the record type
        if (Record::RECORD_TYPE_TXT == $record->getType()) {
            // split on any double quotes with a space
            $content = explode('" "', $record->getContent());
            // recombine the string
            $content = implode('', $content);
            // remove any stray double quotes
            $content = str_replace('"', '', $content);

            $output->content = $content;
        } else {
            $output->content = $record->getContent();
        }

        $output->id = $record->getId();
        $output->name = $record->getName();
        $output->ttl = $record->getTtl();
        $output->type = $record->getType();
        $output->priority = $record->getPriority();
        $output->zone = $record->getZone();

        return $output;
    }
```

The `@type` is no longer there when GETTING the resource:

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/Record",
    "@id": "/api/records",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "@id": "/api/records/1",
            "id": 1,
            "content": "auth1.dns.mydomain.com hostmaster.mydomain.com 2004021303 3600 900 604800 3600",
            "name": "mydomain.com",
            "ttl": 3600,
            "type": "SOA",
            "zone": {
                "@id": "/api/zones/1",
                "@type": "Zone",
                "id": 1,
                "name": "mydomain.com",
                "type": "NATIVE",
                "recordCount": 7
            },
            "priority": 0
        },
```

Is there another configuration that needs to happen to specify the `@type` in the transformer or on the entity annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug that was fixed in 2.5.8.

https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/3699

Updating to 2.5.9 from 2.5.7 got this working (edited)